# Multi line Text extraction in robot framwork

Tags: regex, string, robotframework

I have text spanning multiple lines. I want to extract text between certain patterns.

```
$cat f1

START:
line1
line2
line3
line4
END
START
line a
line b
line c
END
```

Code below printing empty:

```
   ${txt}    Get File  f1
   ${m}       Get Regexp Matches    ${txt}    START(.*)END    1
   Log To Console     ${m}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that `.` normally will not match a newline. So, `(.*)` will only match up to the end of the line. You can solve this by prefixing the regular expression with `(?s)` which sets the [DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag.

The second problem is that `.*` is *greedy*, meaning it will gobble up as much as possible. Thus, it will get all characters after the first `START` followed by all the characters until the *last* `END`. To make it non-greedy, change it to `.*?` so that it will grab characters after the first `START` and before the first `END`.

With those changes, your statement will look like this:

```
${m}    Get Regexp Matches    ${txt}    (?s)START(.*?)END    1
```

That will result in two matches (split out for clarity):

- `:\nline1\nline2\nline3\nline4\n`
- `\nline a\nline b\nline c\n`

If you don't want the newlines, you'll need to do some further massaging of the data.